# Show tooltip when hover on top left 2 px square of div JavaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript

I want to make JavaScript function when hover on top left 2px square of div like demo on first comment but when hover on the top left 2 px square. To show tooltip or trigger any function. Check example on first comment and I want it to show L when hover on top left 2 px square

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/58Qdw/3/